# AWS Lambda, DynamoDB unable to delete object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

this is my lambda function

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var params = {
    TableName: 'xx',
    Key: {
        project_id : event.id,
        name: event.name
    }
};

docClient.delete(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
         callback(null, data);
     }}
 );
};
```

my test event is

```
{
"id": "1490022172442",
"name":"xcv"
}
```

And still i got error  "The provided key element does not match the schema". POST and GET is working nice but I am stucked here.

Comment: Does your table has project_id defined as hash key and name as sort key? what do you mean by GET and POST are working fine? Do you mean create item and get item are working fine?

Comment: That was the reason, I missed sort key!

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete an item from DynamoDB table, you have to provide both partition and sort key in key attributes. It should work if you include sort key on key attributes.

Comment: Is there any other way to getItem using only index key ?

Answer (score 0):

Below given is a code snippet for deleting an item where there is only primary key and no sort key is provided

```
ar AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
console.log('event= ' + JSON.stringify(event));
console.log('context= ' + JSON.stringify(context));

var params = {
TableName: 'TableName',
Key: {
    kundeId : event.kundeId,
    name: event.name
}
};

docClient.delete(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
} else {
     console.log("DEBUG:  deleteItem worked. ");
    context.succeed(data);

 }}
 );
 };
```